# Where are the platform services in eclipse rcp/e4?

Tags: dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have the latest eclipse rcp/e4 and I'm trying to access the platform services listed here:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Services/article.html

However, I can't even find ECommandService, EHandlerService or any IEclipseContext type object.  I do however have the ability to inject EModelService and EContextService.

I'm simply trying to execute a handler/command from my code, and I think I need to @inject those objects above and execute them.  I don't see any documentation saying this process has changed, so what would I need to do?

My ultimate goal is to create a Button somewhere, and cause it to change perspectives.  My strategy is to put this in a handler, and then in there, use the modelService to find that perspective and switch to it.

I'm using the Eclipse Mars 4.5.1, and Eclipse E4 Tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just need to add the appropriate plugins to your plugin dependencies (Set this on the 'Required Plug-ins' list on the 'Dependencies' tab in the MANIFEST.MF editor).

`ECommandService` and `EHandlerService` are in the `org.eclipse.e4.core.commands` plugin.

`IEclipseContext` is in the `org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts` plugin.

Comment: You are right.  I could not find instructions to set this up properly.